# SAS: Macro variable and string. Correct TableName

Tags: string, macros, dataset, sas

This is a part of macro:

```
  %let mvTableName = "MyTable";

  proc append base = &mvTableName data = TEMP_TABLE;
  run;
```

And i can't find table in WORK :\

After that i check creation of table.

```
  data &mvTableName; 
  run;
```

And see in log: `Dataset MyTable ...`

But when i change string `%let mvTableName=MyTable;`

I see this log: `Dataset WORK.MyTable ..`

How it can be explained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to use mvTableName as an input for a DATA= option, don't include double quotes

Assuming MyTable and Temp_table are SAS data sets in the WORK library...this should work.

```
%Let mvTableName=MyTable;
Proc Append base=&mvTableName data=temp_table;
run;
```

Also,

```
Data &mvTableName;
Run;
```

Creates an empty data set...so mvTableName would be overwritten with an empty data set.

Comment: In macro variable assignment everything after the = until the ; is assigned to the macro variable...unlike a data step variable assignment which will not include the quotes. The quotes were being included in the BASE= statement...which is incorrect. It is rare (some would say it should never happen) that quotes are used in a macro variable assignment. If you need quotes in your statement...just wrap the macro var. Be sure to use double quotes or the macro variable will not resolve.